# Unsure of outcome of nvidia driver update

Tags: drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, updates

I wanted to update my graphics card driver, so I downloaded the latest version from nvidia and installed it (*didn't uninstall or do anything to the driver already on my computer*).

However, when I go to the *nvidia control panel* it says I'm still running the old version, and when I go to *Programs and Features* in the windows control panel, only the old version shows up. But, under `C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver` only the new version shows up. In addition, the installer said the installation was a success, and the screen went black during parts of the installation which I take as a sign that something must have been changed.

So, Is there any way to check which version my computer is really running, or should I just uninstall whatever is there and reinstall?

P.S.

- I have restarted my computer
- Old driver version is 311.06
- New driver version is 365.10
- Graphics card is GeForce GTX 560 Ti
- OS is Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: Download the installer for the current Nvidia drivers.  Until the drivers you have installed, restart your computer, then install the drivers.

Comment: clean up driver using "display driver uninstaller" (google it)

Answer (score 0):

If your NVIDIA control panel says you're running the old version this means the update was in fact confused somehow and you have some unusual mixed state now between old and new. In this case you really need to do a clean install of the latest driver.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that all the installation did was only "extracting" it and saving it into the `C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver` folder.

I suggest finding the device in Device Manager (Start Menu > Device Manager > Display adapters) > right-click on the device (the graphics card) > click on "Update Driver" > "Browse my computer for driver software > "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer" >>
At this point, if you see your new driver, just select it and proceed with it, otherwise, click on "Have Disk..." > "Browse..." > navigate to the `C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver` folder, delve into the subfolder corresponding with the new driver (until you find the ".inf" file > select it and proceed with the installation.

Bravo! Done!
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're downloading the Nvidia installer from their site not from the GeForce Experience Application;

1. Open the Installer
2. Use `Custom (Advance)`
3. Find the check box marked `Preform Clean Install`

Restart and check now.